# Reading file into Struct, but cannot read past first line in file

Tags: c, sorting, struct, bubble-sort, alphabetical-sort

I am working on an assignment where I need to sort a struct alphabetically based upon an employees surname. I have written the program and can run it, but unfortunately it seems to be removing all of the surnames in the struct.

Right now the program reads data from 40 employees contained in a file into a struct.

Am I missing something in the sorting function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    int employee_code;
    char *employee_surname[20];
    char *employee_forname[20];
    int insurable_weeks;
    float gross_pay;
    float subsidy;
} employee;

employee tempEmployee[100];

void load_data(fp);
void display_menu();
void view_all_employees();
void add_new_employee();
void delete_employee();
void view_qualifying_employees();
void find_disqualified_employees();
void sort_employees_by_subsidy_amount();
void view_total_subsidy_amount();
void sort_employees_by_name();

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");;

    int selection=0, state;
    int n=0;

    load_data(fp);//open file if it exists. If not, create new file. 

    fclose(fp);

    printf("Please choose an option (1-9)...\n");
    do {
        display_menu();
        //scanf("%d", &selection);

        if (state = (scanf("%d", &selection)) != 1) //validates that user is only entering integers.
        {
        printf("\n\n**** Please only enter numbers. Character strings are not accepted. ****\n\n");
        while (getchar() != '\n'); //clears user input to avoid infinite loop. 
        }

        else if (selection < 0 || selection >9)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid entry. Only enter digits between 1-9,\n");
        }

        else
        {
            switch (selection)
            {

            case 1:
                add_new_employee();//view new employees
                break;

            case 2:
                delete_employee();//delete employees
                break;

            case 3:
                view_all_employees();//view all employees and related info
                break;

            case 4:
                view_qualifying_employees();//view employees qualifying for subsidy
                break;

            case 5:
                find_disqualified_employees();//find employees disqualified for subsidy
                break;

            case 6:
                sort_employees_by_name();//sort employee by surname
                break;

            case 7:
                sort_employees_by_subsidy_amount();
                break;

            case 8:
                view_total_subsidy_amount();//total subsidy amount for all employees
                break;



            //more cases added later

            }
        }

    } while (selection != 9);

    printf("\nThank you for using the program! Terminating...\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Here is the function that is causing issues:

```
void sort_employees_by_name()
{
    int n = 100, i, j;
    char temp[20];

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= n - i; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(tempEmployee[j].employee_surname, tempEmployee[j + 1].employee_surname) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, tempEmployee[j].employee_surname);
                strcpy(tempEmployee[j].employee_surname, tempEmployee[j + 1].employee_surname);
                strcpy(tempEmployee[j + 1].employee_surname, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `char *employee_surname[20];` is an array of strings rather than a single string (which would be used as  surname I guess), is that how you want to define it?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` how many records do you have? `100`or `101`?

Comment: I must admit that I am new to using structs in my programming course. I was under the impression that the length of the string had to be declared in the `char *employee_surname` element. When I try to compile the program without it, I receive a compilation error.

Comment: There can potentially be 100 records, though with the data file we received for the assignment only 40 were listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration what you have to store names is an **array of pointers to characters**

```
char *employee_surname[20];
char *employee_forname[20];
```

But you actually need is only an **array of characters**

```
char employee_surname[20];
char employee_forname[20];
```

Regarding the number of records, its better to store the count in some variable or read the file till you see `EOF`.

`for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` is wrong, because you are trying to read more than what you have in your file, get the actual value of `n` and use `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: That actually fixed the issue. I modified the code so that now I am counting the total number of records and that is stored in variable n and it is now not deleting any information. Thank you.